# sublime text 2 move to current workspace

Tags: unity, workspaces, sublime-text

I was wondering if there is way to move ST2, which is already open and on a different workspace, to the current workspace if I open a file with ST2.

It's a bit annoying to search for the ST2 window if the file is open in a tab.

I know I can change the settings such that ST2 opens a new window every time. This could be some workaround, but this is not the behavior I want.

My os is ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Try installing `wmctrl` and running `wmctrl -xR sublime_text.sublime-text-2 && subl file/to/open`. If that works, you can edit the *desktop file* for sublime to always run this command.

Comment: Here is a script: http://odyniec.net/blog/2010/09/moving-windows-to-the-current-workspace-in-gnome-compiz/ that works with Gnome and Compiz. It doesn't do (at least not without modifying, it seems to use `wmctrl`) exactly what you want, but it can be used easily to bring any program to current workspace. I've been using it since 10.10 with Geany for very similar needs.

Answer (score 0):

`subl` has an option `-n` that opens a new window

`subl -n my_file` will open 'my_file' in a new window

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu 16.04, but from what I can tell the command was the same for Sublime Text 2.